# Install packages in parallel

Tags: software-installation, apt, dpkg

If one process of `dpkg` is running i.e installing package or any thing else , why can't we execute another process for `dpkg` in parallel, same for the `apt-get`, Or we can? Is there any tool that can install package in parallel? Windows installer can run in parallel why Linux's don't? What is logic behind this or it is just a design failure?

Comment: As far as I know `dpkg` can't run multiple parallel processes at once. Yes, this might be considered a limitation.

Comment: It lock the database

Answer (score 5):

`dpkg`/`apt` and `rpm`/`yum` use databases that get locked when a package is being installed. This is done on purpose; it is to avoid possible corruption of the databases. The databases are meant for tracking the installed packages on a system.

Comment: this database thing can be solved using database transaction techniques, Right?

Comment: dpkg and rpm create transactions to interact with the database. But that does not mean they will or can run parallel. It's one transaction per installation/removal/search/query of a package.

Comment: This is correct but doesn't explain the logic behind it. The package system could very well identify what can be run in parallel without risk and what not. As other answers point out, this would be technically possible, just not implemented in dpkg/apt. At least not yet!

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to install AppImages. Just make them executable and run!

Before you can run an AppImage, you need to make it executable. This is a Linux security feature. There are three main ways to make an AppImage executable:

**1. With the GUI**

1. Open your file manager and browse to the location of the AppImage
2. Right-click on the AppImage and click the ‘Properties’ entry
3. Switch to the Permissions tab and
4. Click the ‘Allow executing file as program’ checkbox if you are using a Nautilus-based file manager (Files, Nemo, Caja), or click the ‘Is executable’ checkbox if you are using Dolphin, or change the ‘Execute’ drop down list to ‘Anyone’ if you are using PCManFM
5. Close the dialog
6. Double-click on the AppImage file to run

https://sjc2.discourse-cdn.com/standard10/uploads/appimage/optimized/1X/a4889c5cb8711d6845b58135080787d2f370af35_2_500x500.gif

**2. On the command line**

```
chmod a+x Some.AppImage
```

**3. Automatically with the optional appimaged daemon**

If you would like to have all AppImages be executable automatically, you can install the optional `appimaged` daemon. It will automatically add downloaded AppImages to the menu and make them executable for you. It can be downloaded from https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/releases or installed from your distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The base `apt` tool is intentionally simple so that it's easy to reason about what it's doing and hard for it to get itself (or your system) into a bad state. This is why it doesn't do things like contain a solver for dependency conflicts the way `aptitude` does.

Yes, in principle it should be perfectly possible for an installation tool to examine all the candidate packages upfront and identify sets of them which would be safe to download and unpack in parallel— the configure step is still a gap because that's a `postinst` shell script, not something declarative which can be reasoned about by a machine (other than by just invoking it).

Answer (score 0):

You can't run multiple installers on Windows (msi) but most of the ''installers'' are in fact like a script or an appimage. You can install appimages while dpkg installs something